# Uncorrect values displayed from PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display value from a table in My Database.

i'm using a function to Select the Datas :

```
public static function getCommandeFromEntrepriseId($bdd, $id) {
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM Commande WHERE entreprise_id='$id'";
    $commandes = getResultatRequete($bdd, $requete);
    return !empty($commandes) ? $commandes : null;
}
```

The SQL request works correctly :
[image: SQL results]

On my controller I using the function like this :

```
$commandes = Commande::getCommandeFromEntrepriseId($bdd, $user->getEntreprise()->getId());
```

And on my Select where I want to use this :

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Sélectionner Devis*</option>
    <?php
    /* @var $commande Commande */
    foreach ($commandes as $commande) {
        echo "<option value='" . $commande['commande_id'] . "'>" . $commande['end_devis'] . "</option>";
    } ?>
</select>
```

The fact is, I'm having a wrong result and i dont understand why...
Here is an exemple :
[image: error exemple]

Here is a var_dumb of my data. :

```
/var/www/html/controllers/client/Front_BonDeCommande.Controller.php:168:
array (size=16)
  'commande_id' => int 1
  0 => int 1
  'lien_devis' => string 'uploads/x/devis/Devis_6_3_2019_10_16_19.xlsx' (length=56)
  1 => string 'uploads/x/devis/Devis_6_3_2019_10_16_19.xlsx' (length=56)
  'lien_bdc' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  'end_devis' => string '2019-04-06 00:00:00' (length=19)
  3 => string '2019-04-06 00:00:00' (length=19)
  'bdc_status' => int 0
  4 => int 0
  'devis_created_by_user_id' => int 32
  5 => int 32
  'bdc_managed_by_user_id' => int 32
  6 => int 32
  'entreprise_id' => int 6
  7 => int 6
```

Can you tell me what's wrong ? I don't understand...

Comment: You have only one element in `var_dump`.

Comment: Correct... But I don't understand why...

Comment: Because some of used functions return only one result.

Comment: What's in `getResultatRequete` ?

Comment: how are you doing he actual query/getting the result.  I suspect its a fetch instead of fetchAll issue, but would beed to see the code

Comment: The same thing that what I have in my var_dumb

Comment: It is `var_dumP`. And people ask you to provide code for `getResultatRequete`.

Comment: For the query, I use the function inside my class `getCommandeFromEntrepriseId`then on my Controller i saved it in my a var called $commande and then use it in my foreach

Comment: Do you understand that `Commande::getCommandeFromEntrepriseId` __uses__ `getResultatRequete` which in turn, returns you only one record?

Comment: I'm just stupid I have 2 fonctions `getResultatRequete` and ` getResultatsRequete`.. One return just one result and the other one all the results I just failed...
Yhank your help and support